# How i can add rxtx

Tags: java, rxtx

I have a problem with the native library, I wanted to add RXTX got this error message:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.<clinit>(CommPortIdentifier.java:123)
    at indu.CommPortLister.list(CommPortLister.java:24)
    at indu.CommPortLister.main(CommPortLister.java:17)
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the rtrxSerial.so (of rtrxSerial.dll) on the classpath. This is very well explained in the documentation.